# Como ver las subviews de una UIView dentro de una UIView Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Como puedo ver los componentes de una vista dentro de otra vista 
Como veo los componentes de la vista principal:

```
NSArray *sub = [self.view subviews];
if ([sub count] == 0) return;
for (int i=0; i<sub.count; i++){
  NSLog(@"Subview: %@", sub[i]);
}
```

Y si me da los componentes que tiene esa vista pero que pasa si esa vista tiene otra vista dentro con otras subview como las puedo identificar, ya intente con:

```
NSArray *sub = [self.view subviews];
    if ([sub count] == 0) return;
    for (int i=0; i<sub.count; i++){

        if ([sub[i] isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            NSArray *sub1 = [sub[i] subviews];
            for (int x=0; x<sub1.count; x++){
                NSLog(@"ssssssss:::::::::::%@", sub1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Pero no es que no funcione, pero reconoce los botones como SUBVIEW y me jala el componente que tiene dentro digamos que si el botón tienen una imagen me dice que adentro tiene un UIImageview y si tiene texto un UIButtonLabel me explican que es lo que pasa y como obtener solo los que tiene ese UIView en ese momento, SOLO de los UIView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno como siempre soy el único loco que responde a sus preguntas siempre.
Que pasa, descubrí que los UIIbutton funcionan como un UIView además de UIButton debido a que para almacenar texto o una imagen funcionan con un UIView generando una nueva subview ya sea de tipo UIImageview o UIButtonlabel.

Al parecer no hay manera de evitar eso así que lo arregle con una simple condición.

```
NSArray *sub = [self.view subviews];
    if ([sub count] == 0) return;
    for (int i=0; i<sub.count; i++){

        if ([sub[i] isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] && [sub[i] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            // Un UIButton se reconoce igual como un UIView
        }
        else if ([sub[i] isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]){
            NSArray *sub1 = [sub[i] subviews];
            for (int x=0; x<sub1.count; x++){
                NSLog(@"ssssssss:::::::::::%@", sub1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Lo demás se explica solo.